# Improving Sprite Kit application

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I am now finishing my first app I developed in Xcode. 
Now i want to improve smoothness of my app. Sometimes my app freezes for really short time. If you would played it for first time, you wouldn't noticed, but for me it is a nightmare.

Maybe my sounds causing that problem (i am running them on different thread but anyway), or something else..

What is the best way to test my app? Are there some special programs to do it?

Comment: "Instruments", a tool that comes with Xcode (Right click Xcode in the Dock, choose "Open Developer Tool" and then "Instruments") can help you monitor a number of things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing you can do in Xcode: Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme -> Build Configuration -> Release.
If you e.g. work much with arrays, it will speed up your app.

You can then also use [Instruments](http://www.raywenderlich.com/23037/how-to-use-instruments-in-xcode) to test the behavior of your app.